# Why are my Swing JButtons odd sizes?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to create an interface for a game similar to that of 'Who Wants to be a Millionaire' but I am having no luck with the layouts.

The code for my latest attempt:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class GameGUI extends JFrame //implements ActionListener
{
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    JButton btnQuestion = new JButton();
    JButton btnAnsA = new JButton();
    JButton btnAnsB = new JButton();
    JButton btnAnsC = new JButton();
    JButton btnAnsD = new JButton();

    Color customDarkGrey = new Color(20, 20, 20);

    public GameGUI()
    {
        super("Game");
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane.setBackground(customDarkGrey);
        contentPane.add(pnl); pnl.setOpaque(false);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pnl.add(btnQuestion, c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.weighty = 0.5;
        c.ipadx = 40;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pnl.add(btnAnsA, c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        pnl.add(btnAnsA, c);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Displays this:
[image]

The strips across both the middle and top are buttons

I have tried using other layouts but every time the buttons seem to come out too small to be used as intended.

Can anyone suggest a combination of layouts to achieve the desired layout (question in the centre and 4 answer choices below in a 2x2 grid)?

Note:
I'm completely new to stackoverflow (not like I'm stating the obvious or anything). I can't comment on posts or other comments as I don't have any reputation so in trying my best to communicate with you -user1803551- the only way I could see how was through edits. Suggest something else and I will adhere to that, but until then I'd appreciate it if you would stop reverting the post.

Comment: screenshot of what your gui looks like?

Comment: In your code you are only adding the A answer button and the question button. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Updated with the screenshot..

Comment: Don't edit your question in response to answers, comment on the answers instead. I'm reverting your edit. Reply to comments using @<username> .

Answer (score 5):

In your code you are only adding `btnQuestion` and `btnAnsA`, so no wonder is doesn't work.

Anyway, I used your initial `GridBagLayout` approach.

- The question button was given a width of 2 so it would span properly.
- I added arbitrary insets, but it's at your discretion.
- You didn't specify clear resizing behavior, I gave an arbitrary one.

[image]

```
public class GameGUI extends JFrame {

    JButton btnQuestion = new JButton("This is the Question");
    JButton btnAnsA = new JButton("This is answer A");
    JButton btnAnsB = new JButton("This is answer B");
    JButton btnAnsC = new JButton("This is answer C");
    JButton btnAnsD = new JButton("This is answer D");

    public GameGUI() {

        super("Game");

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        getContentPane().add(pnl);

        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.weighty = 0.5;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        pnl.add(btnQuestion, c);

        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        pnl.add(btnAnsA, c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        pnl.add(btnAnsB, c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        pnl.add(btnAnsC, c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        pnl.add(btnAnsD, c);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new GameGUI());
    }
}
```

If you don't want to mess with GBL, a compound layout approach will be very simple (can demonstrate on request).